# Content query webpart - calendar issue with reccuring events

Tags: sharepoint, events, calendar, caml, cqwp

I have a content query webpart that read the calendar list and display **currently running events**.

The issue I have is when I set up a recurring event, my query gets "*broken*".

#### My CAML request :

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="EventDate" Nullable="False" Type="DateTime"/>
            <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">
            <Today />
            </Value>
        </Leq>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="EndDate" Nullable="False" Type="DateTime"/>
            <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">
            <Today />
            </Value>
        </Geq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Problem is, recurring events are defined with an EventDate of ***whenever it starts***, but the EndDate is something like ***in 10 years from now*** (or in year **4499** O_o ).

Here's the identity output of a recurring event (it seems nothing define it like that... at least, from the info I can toy with).

```
Property:ListId | Value:<gibberish>
Property:WebId | Value:<gibberish>
Property:ID | Value:17
Property:Title | Value:maint
Property:FileRef | Value:SiteDirectory/mysite/Lists/Calendrier/17_.000
Property:_x007B_1d22ea11_x002D_1e32_x002D_424e_x002D_89ab_x002D_9fedbadb6ce1_x007D_ | Value:17
Property:Modified | Value:2011-07-05 10:37:02
Property:Author | Value:Admin
Property:Editor | Value:Admin
Property:Created | Value:2011-07-05 10:37:02
Property:PublishingRollupImage | Value:
Property:_Level | Value:1
Property:Comments | Value:
Property:EventDate | Value:2011-07-05 03:00:00
Property:EndDate | Value:2021-01-26 05:00:00
Property:fAllDayEvent | Value:0
Property:LinkUrl | Value:http://localhost/SiteDirectory/mySite/Lists/Calendrier/17_.000
Property:PubDate | Value:Tue, 05 Jul 2011 14:37:02 GMT
Property:ImageUrl | Value:
Property:ImageUrlAltText | Value:
Property:Description | Value:
Property:Style | Value:identity
Property:GroupStyle | Value:Band
Property:__begincolumn | Value:True
Property:__begingroup | Value:False
```

(This event is defined as happening every Monday and Tuesday).

1. **How can I know if an event is recurrent or not?**
2. **How could I filter my query to contains only currently running occurrence of a periodic event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to realise is that a recurring event series is stored as just one event, not as each individual instance.

Hence the start/end dates being so long - its the total length of the recurrance, not any particular instance.

There is an fRecurrance field that is True if you are dealing with a recurring event.

This is about the only guide you will find for understanding recurring events - but heads up, working with recurring events is hard work and that way lies anger, hate and suffering...

[MSDN - Understanding the SharePoint calendar and how to export it to iCal format](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=761)

Comment: I had read that article already (between question time and answer time). Helped a lot. _fRecurrence_ for my 1st question, _RecurrenceData_ for my 2nd question, but yeah, your comment on anger, hate and suffering his accurate, I'm still stuck :D